# Interpreting 'not booked' on IRCTC

Tags: india, indian-railways, irctc

I've tried to book train tickets for a group of three on IRCTC. I got up to the payment screen for a payment processor, put in my details, and then was routed back to the payment processor selection screen.

I logged in again to IRCTC and it said the ticket was 'NOT BOOKED' - see below. Does this mean that payment failed or that the seats ('berths') were not available in the same coach? I selected 'Book, only if all berths are allotted in same coach'

[image: IRCTC with status NOT BOOKED]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it was that the transaction hadn't gone through. I had used an Indian payment processor for an international card. Instead, I needed to use 'International Cards Powered by PayU'. When I did that, the booking was confirmed.